# React Navigation: how to access component related to path in the URL?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-web

On my **React Native app (web implementation, with Expo managed workflow)**, I have implemented **react navigation**. I have everything based on Stack. Apparently, there is a good match between the paths and the components associated to those paths. **Example**: when I visit the log-in page, I can read in the URL `myapp/log-in`, if I go to settings, I can read `myapp/settings`.

However, when I try to manually type my URL: `myapp/settings`, I am taken to my initial route (`myapp/log-in`). I'm trying to do this, my goal is that from an external site, I can directly take the user to `myapp/settings`.

For trying to achieve my goal, I went basically through all the documentation related to this and can't find what I'm doing wrong:

- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/web-support
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#linking

I already created an issue on **GitHub**: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11162

On my example repository, you can confirm the behavior I'm describing: https://github.com/JMRMEDEV/navigation-issues, the README has some extra details on the implementation.

- I already tried different setup like defining my `schema` on my `app.json`
- I tried to set my prefixes on my config.
- I tried to remove the `Stack.Group` (thinking that probably could be taken as a nested `navigator` and use `Stack.Screen` as components in the top level.
- I tried to define my screens config as objects instead of strings **EG:** `Settings: {path: 'settings'}` instead of `Settings: 'settings'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that in the documentation, the following concept is not that clear:

We have our config object:

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: 'home',
    SignUp: 'sign-up',
  },
};

const linking = {
  config,
  prefixes: [prefix],
};
```

In here, I thought that `Chat` and `Profile` referred to the actual **react components** (since they are usually referred as **screens**), but I noticed that they were referring to the **screen names**. Therefore, when we have something like:

```
<NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={'home'}
    screenOptions={{
      animation: 'none',
      headerShown: false,
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen component={Home} name="home" />
    <Stack.Screen component={SignUp} name="signUp" />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

The cited config object will not work (due to the sensitive casing), and should be updated to something like:

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: 'home',
    signUp: 'sign-up', // The key will be the screen name and the value will be the path
  },
};
```